# How to retrieve data as json in fields from mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, json, subquery, mysql-json

this question may be weird or maybe unknown to me so i wanted to make sure is it possible or not .
this is very basic query

```
select * from table;

and the output is like

id,
column1,
column2,
.
.
.
```

okay what i was thinking about json on mysql is there any way to subquery data and embed it into fields like this

```
select *,(select * from table2) as jsonData from table;

which outputs something like this 

Id,
column1,
column2,
jsonData = {
 "Id",
 "column1-of-table2",
 "column2-of-table2",
 .
 .
},
.  
.
```

since i have not done this kind of query in my sql ever so i am little curious about it ,
please mention if this is not clear, and any help would really help me
Thank you !!

Comment: Provide complete sample: CREATE TABLE for all tables, INSERT INTO with sample data (3-5 rows enough), desired output for this data. Do not forget to provide precise MySQL version.

Comment: Also mention relation between your tables is it 1:1 or 1:many